# Why does the property edited value persists?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

By reading a question about `concurrency` on a collection made by another user, I started trying to write my own `threadsafe list class`.

After doing that I made a testcase, which i used to try and it ended up throwing errors on a `foreach`, because of the original `GetEnumerator` method which was:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (Lock)
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I wrote it again (by reading some tips on the internet), this way, and it worked. I tought it was just returning a copy of the `original collection's enumerator`:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (Lock)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumeratorCopy = List.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumeratorCopy.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return enumeratorCopy.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then for curiosity, i tried to edit a property of a given `class`, and I noticed that the edited values, were persisting.

Can you explain me why? Is `yield` giving a `reference` instead of just the `value`?

This is the full code:

```
class Program
{
    private static ThreadSafeList<Dog> Dogs = new ThreadSafeList<Dog>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Dogs.Add(new Dog(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });

        while (true)
        {
            Print("{0} - There are {1} Dogs registered.", DateTime.Now, Dogs.Count);
            foreach (Dog dog in Dogs)
            {
                Print("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now, dog);
                dog.EditCreationDateTime(default(DateTime));
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    private static void Print(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(message, args));
    }
}

public class Dog
{
    public Guid Guid { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; private set; }

    public Dog(string name)
    {
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
        CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{{ Guid: {0}, Name: {1}, CreationDateTime: {2} }}", Guid, Name, CreationDateTime);
    }

    public void EditCreationDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        CreationDateTime = dateTime;
    }
}

public class ThreadSafeList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    private List<T> List { get; set; }
    private object Lock { get; set; }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                return List.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public ThreadSafeList()
    {
        List = new List<T>();
        Lock = new object();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                return List[index];
            }
        }

        set
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                List[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            List.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            using (IEnumerator<T> enumeratorCopy = List.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumeratorCopy.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return enumeratorCopy.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            using (IEnumerator<T> enumeratorCopy = List.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumeratorCopy.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return enumeratorCopy.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you try and write your own thread-safe collection when there are ones built into the framework already? Threading code is notoriously complex, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @DavidG just to try it, sometimes I like to see things deeper

Comment: Then read the code of the [existing objects](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/5955ee2583d4509d37ecf55243e9e3c9af128487/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs).

Comment: @DavidG thank you for the useful link, my question is still valid, it's about a different thing which i'm not understanding

Comment: It may be, but you're unlikely to find someone to decode this large block of code for you, that's what debugging is for :)

Comment: Well they need it to answer to my question, and I made it so

Comment: An object is persistant by itself - so if you change the properties of that object, it will have those changes no matter where you access it. It just has 1 state thats identically in every thread, if you like to have an object with different states in different threads you have to make it yourself by for exmple using ThreadLocal - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1

Comment: I don't think that your question has anything to do with multithreading. You would observe the same behavior with a simple `List<Dog>` enumerated on a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

Dog is `class`, which makes it a [Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

> There are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types. Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects), while variables of value types directly contain their data. With reference types, two variables can reference the same object; therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced by the other variable. With value types, each variable has its own copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one variable to affect the other (except in the case of in, ref and out parameter variables; see in, ref and out parameter modifier).

The objects being `yield`ed are referencing the exact same objects in the private `List` property.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `CreationDateTime` change.

"`Print` infinite loop" print first time before the value change.

When loop exit, it's start a new loop, in the same time `Task` added a new elements into a list of dogs.

"`Print` infinite loop" restart the loop, reprint element with changed value in `CreationDateTime` and print a new dogs added after a first loop.

And so on...